# Fling on pinch gesture in Android

Tags: android, multi-touch

I know `GestureDetector` has an `onFling()` callback method, we can use it to have smooth horizontal/vertical scroll effect after the user lifted his finger.

Is there an equivalent in `ScaleGestureDetector`? The desired effect is to keep zooming after the user made a quick **pinch** gesture.